# Wordpress using // without http or https?

Tags: php, wordpress

For some reason my wordpress blog is using // to the path to resources.  For example:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="//my.site.com/"/>
```

This is not good for SEO, but I can't seem to figure out where to go to fix this.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

go to wp-config.php, in your wordpress root, and try to change these two lines to add your website url,

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

and open the functions.php file and make below changes,

```
update_option('siteurl','http://example.com');
update_option('home','http://example.com');
```

and also try these steps,

```
1)Login to WordPress admin dashboard
2)Click on Settings >> General
3)Fill in your WordPress Address and Site Address and click Save.
```

finally these steps,

```
1)Backup your database in cPanel prior to making changes.
2)Use phpMyAdmin to manage your WordPress database.
3)phpMyAdmin select WordPress databaseSelect your WordPress database from the left.
4)Then select your wp_options table.
5)Click Edit beside either the siteurl or home entries.
6)Enter in your new value in the option_valuie field, then click Go
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

at the last try to refer,

```
http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/wordpress/wordpress-changing-the-site-url-and-home-settings
```

Comment: This unfortunately didn't work.  You can see for yourself at my site: https://blog.trekeffect.com

Comment: yes it opened the website, where is this issue of //